# PHP prevent user add data in TIME range

Tags: php, mysql

I have t_meeting like this :

```
meeting_date | meeting_from | meeting_to | meeting_room
```

Example I have a data like this :

```
2013-09-03   | 08:00        | 09:00      | Meeting 1
2013-09-03   | 09:00        | 10:00      | Meeting 1
```

Now, how can I prevent user to add meeting if the meeting time has been booked.
Example if user want to add meeting in same date and meeting room but different time.

```
2013-09-03   | 08:30        | 09:00      | Meeting 1 <-- how to prevent it
```

I mean, how to block the time range. We see 08:30 still in time range booked.

and here is my SQL code so far :

```
$check_meeting = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_meeting WHERE meeting_date = '$meeting_date' && meeting_room = '$meeting_room' && meeting_from >= '$meeting_time_from' && meeting_from <= '$meeting_time_from' && meeting_to <= '$meeting_time_to' && meeting_to >= '$meeting_time_to'");                 

if(mysql_num_rows($check_meeting) > 0)
{
echo "<div class='warns errors'>Duplicate data meeting!</div>";
}
else
{query save}
```

Comment: how to block the time range. We see 08:30 still in time range booked. Please read first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE `meeting_date` = $date
  AND `meeting_from` <= $to
  AND `meeting_to` >= $from
```

If the condition above returns anything - then the given interval intersects with one that is already booked

Comment: 8:00 to 9:00 and 9:00 to 10:00 is by example allowed, your query would block 10:00 - 11:00

Comment: @Xevelion: it's up to user to decide if he needs strict `>` or `>=` comparisons. I'm sure they know about `>` and `>=` difference

Answer (score 2):

The conditions that specify an overlap are that the meeting starts *before* any existing meeting end, and the meeting ends *after* any existing meeting starts.  In SQL this is:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_meeting
WHERE meeting_date = '$meeting_date' AND meeting_room = '$meeting_room' AND
      meeting_from <= '$meeting_time_to' AND
      meeting_to >= '$meeting_time_from';
```

Comment: In db: `0-2`, passed: `1-3` - won't overlap according to your query, while it does. The correct condition for overlap is in my answer :-) (ps: downvote isn't mine)

Comment: @no reply: you have mistake in your sql query, and Gordon Linoff had fixed it

Comment: I tried for meeting from if still in range, it will block. But if I add meeting to out of time meeting booked. it will saved. Any idea ?

Comment: @No Reply: any idea for what?

Comment: I mean how about if the (meeting to) out of time booked ? Ex: start meeting 09:00 <-- OK I know it will block cause it still in range if time booked. End meeting 10:30 <-- we see the time end meeting out of time booked. Please see in my example above.

Comment: @NoReply . . . Your example is prevented by this logic (and the logic in zerkms's answer as well).  The start is before the end, and the end is after the start.